# broken for loop

Tags: solidity, contract-development, solidity-0.8.x, math, safemath

can someone let me know what i got wrong in this for loop, if you need the full code let me know.

```
function calculateSplitPercent() public {
    for(uint256 i = 0; i >= uniqueIdCounter; i++) {
        uint256 spliPercent = balanceOf[uniqueIdToAddress[i]].div(totalFunded).mul(100);
        addrsToSplitPercentage[uniqueIdToAddress[i]] = spliPercent;
        splitPercentageToAddrs[spliPercent] = uniqueIdToAddress[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function calculateSplitPercent() public {
    for(uint256 i = 0; i <= uniqueIdCounter; i++) {
        uint256 spliPercent = balanceOf[uniqueIdToAddress[i]].div(totalFunded).mul(100);
        addrsToSplitPercentage[uniqueIdToAddress[i]] = spliPercent;
        splitPercentageToAddrs[spliPercent] = uniqueIdToAddress[i];
    }
}
```